# How to remove duplicate lines that begin with a pattern and the next line after that?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to remove duplicate lines that begin with `>` and the next line after that.

For example:

```
>1
ACCGGTTTCCTTGAAATT
>2 
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
>3 
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
>1 
ACCGGTTTCCTTGAAATT
```

As you can see I have the next two duplicated lines:

```
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT and >1
```

However I only want to remove `>1` and the next line, so I want and output like:

```
>1
ACCGGTTTCCTTGAAATT
>2
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
>3
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
```

If I use something like:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++'  filename
```

The output is:

```
>1
ACCGGTTTCCTTGAAATT
>2
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
>3
```

Because it removes all duplicated lines and I only want to remove duplicated lines that begin with `>` and the next line after that.

My true file is about several thousand of lines so I could have several names after the symbol `>` that could be repeated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getline` in your awk to fetch the next line:

```
awk '/^>/{ if(!seen[$0]++){ print;getline;print } else { getline } }'
```

---

There is a simpler answer that also handles multiple lines:

```
awk '/^>/{ skip = seen[$0]++ }
     { if(!skip)print }'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

This respond exactly my question. I also had cases with more than two lines after >, thus I use: 

awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n", $0); next; } {printf ("%s", $0);} END {print("\n");}' filename | awk '/^>/{ if(!seen[$0]++){ print;getline;print } 

The first code to linearize the sequence and your code to eliminate repetitive sequences that begin with >, just if some one else have the same problem
 
Thank you very much again.

Comment: I added a simpler solution that should also handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX tools chest:

```
paste - - <file | awk '{$1=$1};!seen[$0]++' | tr '\t' '\n'
```

Comment: Nice. I'd use `paste` instead of `sed`.

Comment: I don't see the problem: `paste - - < file | awk '{$1=$1} !seen[$0]++' | tr '\t' '\n'`

Comment: @glennjackman: In my above comment, I mean trailing spaces. Anyway, your one is better. Added to my answer with posixified `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR%2==1{l=$0;next} !seen[l"\n"$0]++{print l"\n"$0}' file
```

- `NR%2==1` is true every 2nd line, so the lines with `>1`, `>2` and `>3`. In this case save that content to a variable `l` and continue with the `next` line.
- `!seen[l"\n"$0]++` here we don't check for unique lines, we check for **2** unique consecutive lines.

  - If they are unique, print the last line `l` and the current line `$0` with a newline `\n` between them.

---

The output:

```
>1 
ACCGGTTTCCTTGAAATT
>2 
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
>3 
AACCTTCCGGTTAATT
```

Comment: 1) `NR%2` is enough (without `==1`); 2)`[l$0]` there is no reason to put `\n` inside of index 3)* `print l;print` looks better than `print l"\n"$0`

Comment: @Costas I used `[l"\n"$0]` on purpose, because a line could contain `l` followed by `$0` (and wouldn't be printed), but not with a newline between: it would be 2 lines then.

Comment: Line couldn't contain `l followed by $0` because each line is `$0` only

Comment: @Costas The **current** line not, but a line that was processed before and is now index of `seen`.

Comment: Understand. You mean something like `>1A AAB` and `>1 AAAB`? Agree. I hope it is not the case, but for future [l,$0] looks better then [l"\n"$0]

Comment: @Costas No, `l` could be anything (or could *have been*). And I mean the index of seen, not the current `l`

Comment: Agree. See my above comment edited.

Comment: @Costas sure, I didn't mean any harm =) ... But the comma `,` as mentioned in the comment, is also not 100% save (in this case). The only thing that is 100% save is a newline, because that will never occure in a single line (disregarding of the lines end)...

Comment: Be noted that by default inside of awk array index `,` is not a `comma` but special SUBSEP symbol — `"\034"`

Comment: @Costas Ah, I see, this variable has the default the value `\034`, insterresting.

Comment: Y'd see this by `awk 'BEGIN{a[1, 2]=1;for (i in a)print i}'`